# SQL view Select Statement - convert to decimal where not null

Tags: sql-server, view, crystal-reports, decimal

How can I create a select statement for a view and inside of it, convert the datatype of the OverallSat Column from nvarchar(10) to a decimal(10,2) only where the values are not null. Crystal reports is having a difficult time with this column.
Current Statement:

```
SELECT [BPF_FR_ID]
  ,[ResolveDate]
  ,[Organization]
  ,[AssigneeGroup]
  ,[Survey_Category]
  ,[HDATechComp]
  ,[TechComp]
  ,[ProfCourt]
  ,[Timeliness]
  ,[OverAllSat]
  ,[KeySent]
  ,[CheckSave]
  ,[TicketNumber]
  ,[Form]
FROM [NotesData].[dbo].[BPF_FinanceReport_tbl]
```

I am looking to replace the value of [OverAllSat] with something like this...

```
Select OverAllSat, 
   Case When IsNumeric(OverAllSat)<>0 THEN 
       CONVERT(nvarchar(10),CONVERT(decimal(10,2),OverAllSat))
   ELSE 
      OverAllSat
   End as  OverAllSat
From [NotesData].[dbo].[BPF_FinanceReport_tbl]
```

Is this possible through a view selection criteria, or does it have to be somewhere else(trigger on insert/update).  any Examples are greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: One column can only have ONE data type, you cannot possibly convert some rows to a specific data type and others to a different data type.

Comment: Using crystal for this will make life simple...dont manipulate through query...instead use crystal formulas

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ISNULL()`

```
Select OverAllSat, 
   Case When IsNumeric(ISNULL(OverAllSat,0)) = 1 THEN 
      CONVERT(decimal(10,2),OverAllSat)
   ELSE 
      CONVERT(decimal(10,2),ISNULL(OverAllSat,0))
   End as  OverAllSat1
From [NotesData].[dbo].[BPF_FinanceReport_tbl]
```

Or if you are really strict about how it has not to be null then you have to add it to your case condition.

```
Select OverAllSat, 
   Case
       When OverAllSat IS NOT NULL AND IsNumeric(OverAllSat) = 1 THEN 
           CONVERT(decimal(10,2),OverAllSat)
       When OverAllSat IS NOT NULL THEN
           CONVERT(decimal(10,2),OverAllSat)
       ELSE
           0
   End as  OverAllSat1
From [NotesData].[dbo].[BPF_FinanceReport_tbl]
```

Comment: I received the error message: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.  examples of the data in the OverAllSat column are  NULL, 4.5, NULL, NULL, 5, NULL, 3.25. Any ideas?

Comment: yes, I didn't check the query you provided earlier but the `CASE` 1st condition and 2nd condition have different type after converting them (1st condition is in `nvarchar` and the 2nd condition is in `decimal`. I fixed the query, should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to separate that out to two columns. One that is decimal(10,2) and the other that is varchar(10). This sort of formatting task should be left to your presentation layer if possible.